# Mechanism to display JSON array in checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, json, checkbox

I used the JSON to create an array multidimensional. Now my problem is how to make groups of checkboxes  (into tables or in anything to make possible separating them,  by horizontal bars for example).

This is a example of the lines of the file:

```
{"id": "v0", "namegroup": "Table rules create OR insert", "rule": "All classes give origin to a table.", "value": 0}
```

And this is how I create the array:

```
<?php 
$file = fopen("rules.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!"); 
$arrayRules = array();
$i = 0;
while(!feof($file))
{
    $line = fgets($file);
    $content = json_decode(utf8_encode($line), true);
    $arrayRules[$i]['id'] = $content["id"];
    $arrayRules[$i][0] = utf8_decode($content["rule"]);
    $arrayRules[$i]['namegroup'] = $content["namegroup"];
    $arrayRules[$i][1] = $content["value"];
    $i = $i + 1;
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

And this is how I create the checkboxes:

```
echo "<input name=\"regra[]\"  value=\"" . $arrayRules[$i]["id"] . "\" type=\"checkbox\"  /> " . $arrayRules[$i][0] . "<br/> "  ;
```

Remember that the user can edit the name of the group and all the other points.
As you can notice, my problem is not how to echo checkbox, but how will be the mechanism with the purpose of creating and organize the checkboxes by groups.

UPDATE1

For now I have this:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($arrayRules); $i++)
{
    if ($arrayRules[$i]['idgroup'] == 1)
    {
        if  ($arrayRules[$i][1] == 1)
            echo  "<input name=\"regra[]\"  value=\"" . $arrayRules[$i]["id"] . "\" type=\"checkbox\" checked onclick=\"this.checked='checked'\"/> " . $arrayRules[$i][0] . "<br/> "  ;

        if ($arrayRules[$i][1] == 0)
            echo "<input name=\"regra[]\"  value=\"" . $arrayRules[$i]["id"] . "\" type=\"checkbox\"  /> " . $arrayRules[$i][0] . "<br/> "  ;
    }
}
?>
```

the problem is that in `if ($arrayRules[$i]['idgroup'] == 1)` should not be the 1 but should be a variable or something that when every time it finds a new or a diferent name in the file on idgroup it add or create a new table/group of check-boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Add group_id param to your json objects and resort all like

```
 $arrayRules[$group_id][$i]
```

after, you can do something like:

```
foreach($arrayRules as $group_id=>$objects) {
   // start group html
   foreach($objects as $i=>$params) {
       echo "<input name=\"regra[]\"  value=\"" . $params[$i]["id"] . "\" type=\"checkbox\"  /> " . $params[$i][0] . "<br/> "  ;
   }
   // end group html
}
```

Comment: I think the answer i need is more basic than that, just see what i comment in the post in UPDATE1, i got three "for" like that one, and in the midle of them i had a horizontal bar. What i really need is a mechanism that enables to create a divisory of checkboxes when appears a new groupname.